# Python – random is not actually random

Tags: python, random

I use this code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start == [0, roads[0].index('#')]
        while roads[self.start[0]][self.start[1]] == '#':
            self.start[0] = randint(0, len(roads)-1)
            self.start[1] = randint(0, len(roads[0])-1)
        self.start = tuple(self.start)

        self.finish == [0, roads[0].index('#')]
        while roads[self.finish[0]][self.finish[1]] == '#':
            self.finish[0] = randint(0, len(roads)-1)
            self.finish[1] = randint(0, len(roads[0])-1)
        self.finish = tuple(self.finish)

        self.kind = randint(0, 1)
```

What it does is this: in a map represented like this:

```
#############1#########
#############1111######
#############1##1######
#######1111111111######
#############1#########
#############1#########
```

it finds two 1s and sets them as start and finish, then it randomly selects one more variable. Then i do this:

```
a = Car()
b = Car()
```

only to find out that they both have always the same start and finish, but sometimes different kinds. I don't understand – if there is an issue with random not working, it shouldn't work on self.kind as well!
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an equality test here:

```
self.start == [0, roads[0].index('#')]
```

That'll fail unless you have a `start` attribute at the class level; it is **not** assigning, it is testing for equality there. You'd get a `NameError` here!

So, you probably *do* have a `Car.start` class attribute, and it is a mutable type, like a list:

```
class Car:
    start = [0, 0]
```

but forgot to include that in your question.

You then assign to `self.start` indices, the class attribute:

```
self.start[0] = randint(0, len(roads)-1)
self.start[1] = randint(0, len(roads[0])-1)
```

This is *shared data* as this modifies the class attribute!

Finally, you set an instance attribute:

```
self.start = tuple(self.start)
```

containing shared data. The same applies to your `self.finish` attribute.

You can fix this by using *assignment* rather than an equality test:

```
self.start = [0, roads[0].index('#')]
```

and the same applies to `self.finish`:

```
self.finish == [0, roads[0].index('#')]
```

You could also just use a local name here and assign only to the instance attribute once you are done constructing the lists.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should change your assignments to this:

```
self.start = [0, roads[0].index('#')]
```

and this:

```
self.finish = [0, roads[0].index('#')]
```

Right now, you are using the comparison operator.